# Can starting an intent service multiple times in rapid succession cause null extras?

Tags: android, android-intent

We are seeing an issue where one of our intent services is unexpectedly retrieving a `null` String extra for some of our users. We haven't been able to reproduce this, and we don't know if it is random or consistent on an affected user's device. There doesn't seem to be a correlation between affected users and device type or Android version.

I am extending `IntentService` and implementing the `handleIntent` method like this:

```
@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.Equals(ACTION_MARK_UNREAD)) {
        String messageKey = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_KEY);

        // messageKey is null for some users
    }
}
```

With fields:

```
public static final String ACTION_MARK_UNREAD = "com.myapp.action.MARK_UNREAD";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_KEY = "extraMessageKey";
```

In a fragment, we start this service in rapid succession 6 times:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyIntentService.ACTION_MARK_UNREAD);
            i = i.setClass(mContext, MyIntentService.class);
            i.putExtra(MyIntentService.EXTRA_MESSAGE_KEY, i.toString());
            mContext.startService(i);
    }
```

Any ideas why the service would retrieve `null` for the `messageKey` extra?

We have other areas in the app that start this same service, and we can't identify which one it comes from when this situation happens. However, from looking at logs, it seems to be from this fragment that I mentioned. Logs show that the client timestamp when `null` happens is several seconds after the previous occurrence. This could be because the service queue is slow to move, or my assumption could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the extra is missing? Or is it possible that the `intent` argument passed to `handleIntent()` is `null`?

Comment: @DavidWasser, I went through our code to find every instance of starting this service, and for each instance, we provide a string that is declared as a `public static final String` in a certain class. So I believe we never pass in a `null` value.

Comment: No, you are missing my point. If your service is killed by Android (due to resource requirements or whatever), Android will restart the service later. When it does, it will call `onStartCommand()` passing a `null` intent parameter. That's why I asked if you are sure that it is the **extra** that is missing, or is it possible that `intent == null`?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I know execution goes into the `if` statement of the `handleIntent` method as that's where we log that messageKey is null. Thus I assume `intent` isn't null, or it would fail at `intent.getAction()`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what could be causing your problem then. Starting a Service multiple times like this shouldn't be a problem that I know of.

Comment: Are you overriding onStartCommand of IntentService?

Comment: Really strange, which context are you passing?

Comment: I'm confused why are you doing something six times?  Are you starting a service six times?

Comment: Your code obviously works most of the time but I find it strange that you can use `int i` and `Intent i` and not cause errors.

Comment: As @TTransmit points out, the code you posted is syntactically incorrect (variable `i` is used for `int` and `Intent` and therefore won't compile. Can you please update your post with the actual code that you have? That might help solve your problem.

Comment: Why did you name both intent and integer as `i`? Also are you sure `messageKey` is null? looks like this is not all your code.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this sooner. I can't get back to this code at the moment to try things, but I can assure you the 'i' issue is purely from transcribing our production code to this post. I agree posting the actual code might help; I'll need to come back to this at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is the compiler issue that many other commented about and I figure some other errors on your examples like `Equals` with upper *E* for example.

But considering your code as an example just, I tested a lot this approach and the first thing that I concludes is no matter if your calls are inside a `Fragment` or `Activity` due the `Context` of `Fragment` is the same of parent `Activity`.

Reading the `IntentService` documentation we can read that:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

So we can conclude that all your X requests will be processed enqueued one by one.

Another part at Android documentation about IntentService we can read that:

> Because most started services don't need to handle multiple requests
>   simultaneously (which can actually be a dangerous multi-threading
>   scenario), it's probably best if you implement your service using the
>   IntentService class.

Here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService

So with that information you can think if `IntentService` has been the approach that you need. Right?

Here you can learn how extends just a `Service`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService

Finishing, below I'm pasting the code that I made to test your approach.

Main `Activity` class `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyIntentService.MY_ACTION);

            intent.setClass(this, MyIntentService.class);
            intent.putExtra(MyIntentService.EXTRA, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The `IntentService` `MyIntentService`.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final String MY_ACTION = "my.app.namespace.action.myaction";
    public static final String EXTRA = "my_extra";

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(MY_ACTION)) {
            String messageKey = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA);

            Log.i(EXTRA, messageKey);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output `Log`.

```
my_extra﹕ b6faeb0a-29fa-442b-b87e-9c7a5f8c35d7
my_extra﹕ 88076250-d455-4084-af5f-c560ba6d5570
my_extra﹕ 21339466-25ab-4aaa-aadd-344555c4c2df
my_extra﹕ 2f935a93-465b-4648-a3cc-60f0c9cc67a4
my_extra﹕ 128653d1-d6af-499f-8725-78158e2e7190
my_extra﹕ e453ae7b-e21a-41fe-bf9c-f45ccfd13edf
my_extra﹕ 2e3fc6aa-e425-41dd-a584-8ab056fb906d
my_extra﹕ a8d90d53-c6cd-4d15-84f9-4064d6972de9
my_extra﹕ 721dd17b-b977-4029-ada3-5999f0eb36e7
my_extra﹕ e83d3277-adc8-47a8-a246-6cd7f6f2735d
```

Answer (score 1):

Will you try?

```
for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MyIntentService.ACTION_MARK_UNREAD);
        i = i.setClass(mContext, MyIntentService.class);
        i.putExtra(MyIntentService.EXTRA_MESSAGE_KEY, y.toString());
        mContext.startService(i);
}
```

Could be a compiler issue...